# AS3: How to simplify Action Script 3 Code?

Tags: actionscript-3, simplify, simplification

Here's a example that I've to use when I want to create a button with mouse-over effect:

```
    this.buttonExample.buttonMode = true;
    this.buttonExample.useHandCursor = true;
    this.buttonExample.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myaction);
```

I'm new to AS3 - is there any way, to simplify this code like this:

```
    this.buttonExample.buttonMode = true;.useHandCursor = true;.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myaction);
```

why does it not works ?

Comment: I agree with s.harvey, you can't just make up things and expect that it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Its already as simple as it gets.  Firstly

```
this.buttonExample.buttonMode = true;
this.buttonExample.useHandCursor = true;
this.buttonExample.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myaction)
```

is much more readable than

```
this.buttonExample.buttonMode = true;.useHandCursor = true;.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myaction);
```

Always go for readbility over anything else.  And secondly,

```
this.buttonExample.buttonMode = true;
```

does not return an object so you can't interact with anything.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using that pattern a lot, you can make a helper function:

```
public function setAsButton(button:Sprite, clickHandler:Function):void {
  button.buttonMode = button.userHandCursor = true;
  button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
}
```

Then call it somewhere:

```
setAsButton(this.buttonExample, myaction);
```

Comment: And you can leave out 'this'.

Comment: i'd go a step further and create a class 
var btn:Btn = new Btn(btnExample);
btn.addEventListener(...

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that typing `this.buttonExample` over and over again is too repetitive, simply assign that object to a variable and use that variable in the rest of the statements:

```
var b : Button = this.buttonExample;
b.buttonMode = true;
b.useHandCursor = true;
b.addEventListener(...);
```

As other's have mentioned, there's also the `with` statement, but it's use is discouraged since it makes the code harder to read, and may lead to weird results:

```
with (this.buttonExample) {
  buttonMode = true;
  useHandCursor = true;
  addEventListener(...);
}
```

You can, of course, combine these suggestions with other tricks, like chaining assignments:

```
var b : Button = this.buttonExample;
b.buttonMode = b.useHandCursor = true;
b.addEventListener(...);
```

Be *very* careful to only chain assignments in this way if the assigned value is *immutable* (e.g. `true`, `false`, numbers and strings, but *not* arrays or most other objects), because the *same* object will be assigned to all variables on the left side. If the value is immutable this doesn't matter, but if it's mutable you can end up with weird results, like this in this example:

```
 a = b = [ ];
 a.push(1);
 b.push(2);
 trace(a); // outputs 1, 2
 trace(b); // also outputs 1, 2
```

The reason for this result is that `a` and `b` both reference the *same* array, and since arrays are mutable it doesn't matter how you access the object, it will still be changed. `a` and `b` don't reference different arrays just because they are different variables.

You may think that you could do something like the following, but it will *not* work.

```
// this will NOT work
var b : Button = this.buttonExample;
(b.buttonMode = b.useHandCursor = true).addEventListener(...);
```

The reason why it works to say `b.buttonMode = b.useHandCursor = true`, but not to add `.addEventListener(...)` is that the value of an assignment expression (e.g. `b.buttonMode = true`) is the value *assigned* to the left hand side (e.g. `true`). If you add `.addEventListener(...)` to that you are essentially saying `true.addEventListener(...)`, which clearly is not what you want. In other words

```
b.buttonMode = b.useHandCursor = false;
```

is equivalent to

```
b.useHandCursor = false;
b.buttonMode = b.useHandCursor;
```

Which should hopefully also make the caveats mentioned above plain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`with` statement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#with). however I'd not encourage you to do so, since it leads to a lot of ambiguity and unclearness.

also, you can have multiple assignments:

```
this.buttonExample.buttonMode = this.buttonExample.useHandCursor = true;
```

this sometimes is useful, but for the sake of readability, you shouldn't overuse it.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: I've also read somewhere that "with" in AS3 has performance problems.

Comment: @Shiki: it shouldn't when properties are accessed in a strictly typed manner, but otherwise property resolution becomes rather expensive of course.

Comment: @Richards: It means that at compile time the compiler has knowledge of the type of the property owner, such that the known type defines the property. Consider `class A { public var a:int; }`. And now `var a:A = new A(); var o:* = a;` In this case `a.a` will perform significantly better than `o.a`, because the compiler (in that case the JIT) can calculate the property offset from the information it has, while in the second example it has to be resolved through runtime reflection.